# What is the best location to locate the comments section in a list page

Tags: lists, pagination, comments

I am working in a website representing books, where the user can login and read online books through a book viewer and make hi/her own books collections.

I have implemented a commenting system for each individual book in a separated page as usual the comments section will be underneath the book viewer (so far so good, I have no problemin that page). but the client wants the same commenting system to be over the user collection (over a list page). I mean the website member can comment on a book individual or over a bunch of books located in a certain collection.

My problem is: How to locate the comment section in that case? is it underneath the whole collections list? what if I have pagination? one for the books list in that collection, and other one for the comments.

Where is the best location to locate comments in a list that have pagination?

in the here under example I have a so many problems, I have two pagination, I have the comments under the list and if the list will increase the comments will be in the very low position in the page.

From your point of view and experience, how to solve this problem? where is the best location for the comments system?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLvpU6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You've designed it well. The comments should be beneath the list of books to support consistency with other websites. Comments should be always after the main content of the page. The only thing you can improve, in order to save valuable screen space above the fold of the page is to move the navigation up where the "Website title" area is. You don't want to waste too much space there because most of the visitors have laptop resolutions.

Also, on the sidebar it would be useful if you provide filters for the books, rather than user information, but that off-topic for your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Put a small link to the comments section directly under "Collection Name"**

This will make the comments section discoverable, even if it is low on the page.  It will also help clarify that the comments are associated with the collection.

For the actual comments, putting them on the bottom of the page, as you have shown, might work with this additional cue.

Another option would be hiding them on the main page and having a separate, differently-formatted page for the comments.

Yet another (quite common) option is to hide the comments, but then open them with an accordian fold when someone clicks on the comment link.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely dependant on whether, in the collection view, you intend to show the comments for individual books in a collection or if you only intend to show comments for the collection.

The simplest solution is to only allow comments for the collection - on a collection page you will only show a single board with comments for that particular collection. In this case it's best to just repeat the pattern that your users are already used to: the bottom half of the page is the comments section.

If you're going to include the comments left for each individual then it becomes much more complex as you have to manage the visual/geographic relationship between the book entry in the list and its comments. At this point we move into suggestions: I suggest you employ a mini carousel next to each book entry to show the top few comments (could be most popular, most recent, etc...). I'm assuming that the user can click to get into the page for that individual book. This preserves the relationship between the comments and their respective books and even allows you to add a further comments section in the bottom half of the page for comments about the collection.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbEHj4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>